# Call parent's method from child element

Tags: c#, wpf, parents

in the following structure

```
<Border ...>
    <ItemsControl>
        <ItemsControl.Template>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ACustomElement>
                    <Border MouseLeftButtonDown="method1">
                </ACustomElement>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.Template>
    </ItemsControl>
</Border>
```

I want to call a public method in the ACustomElement class from inside method1().

What I tried so far in method1():

```
var cr = ((Border)sender).Parent;
cr.method2();
```

method2 is a public method in my ACustomElement class. But it doesn't seem to recognize the method.

I'm getting the following error:

> 'DependencyObject' does not contain a definition for 'method2' and no extension method 'method2' accepting a first argument of type 'DependencyObject' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?
Certainly I'm just missing a cast or something else...

Edit: The following style will always be applied to ACustomElement:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type c:ACustomElement}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type c:ACustomElement}">
                <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content}" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: The "Parent" property returns a DependencyObject. Cast it to your "ACustomElement" type

Comment: @nkoniishvt: casting cr to ACustomElement does not solve the problem as mentioned in my comment in Artioms Answer.

Comment: What exactly is ACustomElement? Is it a control?

Comment: It inherits from 'Button'.

Comment: Is the XAML provided in your question the real one? The Parent property should, as far as I know, return your ACustomElement. If it's generated by the ItemContainerStyle you can retrieve it using VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(sender)

Comment: @tg24 if it inherits button, why do you need to catch events of child controls? Set an event handler to your type directly and or use a Command binding.

Answer (score 2):

You have to cast `cr` to ACustomElement type

```
var cr = (ACustomElement)((Border)sender).Parent;
cr.method2();
```

otherwise, your `cr` variable refers to DependencyObject type as you see in the exception.

if you are not sure about hierarchy use this method to find a parent of specific type.

```
private T FindParent<T>(DependencyObject child) where T : DependencyObject {
    var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child) as T;
    if (parent != null)
        return parent;
    return FindParent<T>(parent);
}

// usage
private void method1(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var cr = FindParent<ACustomElement>((Border)sender);
}
```

Also, DateTemplate can be child of ItemsControl.ItemTemplate, but not of ItemsControl.Template (which expects ControlTemplate)

```
 <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
          <local:ACustomElement>
              <Border MouseLeftButtonDown="method1" />
          </local:ACustomElement>
      </DataTemplate>
 </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

**Update**

And as I pointed in the comment to the question, add an event handler to your type directly or bind a command. Why do you make it so complicated?

Comment: I tried to cast cr to ACustomElement type, but it throws the following error: Cannot convert type 'System.Windows.DependencyObject' to 'ACustomElement'.

Comment: @tg24 that doesn't seem right. The cast approach should work

Comment: @tg24 are you sure my code doesn't work? I've checked and it works fine. Except you xaml code seems to have an error

Comment: @Artiom Good point, I did not noticed the "ItemsControl.Template", which confirm that the provided XAML is not the real code trimed down.

Comment: Why not to add an event handler directly to your type?

Comment: I tried this before, but calling method1 (MouseLeftButtonDown="method1" on the ACustomElement element) doesn't execute the method.

Comment: @tg24 I think you try to solve the problem from the wrong way. It's better to close this question and create a new one. As far as I understand, you want to  overrride template of your custom button and set a event handler. Try to do it without events in child elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try to bind the `Tag` property of the `Border` to the custom control:

```
<ACustomElement>
    <Border MouseLeftButtonDown="method1" Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ACustomElement}}">
</ACustomElement>
```

...and cast the `Tag` property in the event handler:

```
var cr = sender as Border;
var ctrl = cr.Tag as ACustomElement;
ctrl.method2();
```

Comment: It does if the "structure" you have posted is actually valid...what does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: The xaml is correct. Note that I added further information concerning the style. "doesn't work" means that ctrl also doesn't seem to be able to call method2() although its type is 'ACustomElement'

Comment: "doesn't seem to be able to call method2"? Are you getting an exception? Otherwise the method is indeed called. Put a breakpoint in it to find out.